# What's the purpose of Just in Elm?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

So, I have been doing the Elm track on [Exercism.org](https://exercism.org/track/elm) and I just finished the exercise about the `Maybe` concept, but one thing is not clear to me yet. What is the purpose of the `Just` in the definition of `Maybe`?

`type Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`

For example, what's the difference between `Int` and `Just Int` and why an integer is not considered a `Just Int` if I don't add the `Just` word before?

More concretely, when I was trying to solve the [RPG problem](https://exercism.org/tracks/elm/exercises/role-playing-game) my first trying resulted in something like this:

```
type alias Player =
    { name : Maybe String
    , level : Int
    , health : Int
    , mana : Maybe Int
    }

revive : Player -> Maybe Player
revive player =
    case player.health of
        0 ->
            if player.level >= 10 then
                Player player.name player.level 100 100
            else
                Player player.name player.level 100 Nothing
        _ ->
            Nothing
```

Just to find out that my mistake was in the if statement, that should return `Just Person`, i.e.:

```
            if player.level >= 10 then
                Just (Player player.name player.level 100 (Just 100))
            else
                Just (Player player.name player.level 100 Nothing)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're coming from a background of dynamic typing like Python then it's easy to see it as pointless. In Python, if you have an argument and you want it to be either an integer or empty, you pass either an integer or `None`. And everyone just understands that `None` is the absence of an integer.

Even if you're coming from a poorly-done statically typed language, you may still see it as odd. In Java, *every* reference datatype is nullable, so `String` is really "eh, there may or may not be a `String` here" and `MyCustomClass` is really "eh, there may or may not really be an instance here". *Everything* can be `null`, which results in everyone constantly checking whether things are `null` at every turn.

There are, broadly speaking, two solutions to this problem: nullable types and optional types. In a language like Kotlin with nullable types, `Int` is the type of integers. `Int`  can *only* contain integers. Not `null`, not a string, not anything else. However, if you *want* to allow `null`, you use the type `Int?`. The type `Int?` is either an integer or a `null` value, and you can't do anything integer-like with it (such as add it to another integer) unless you check for `null` first. This is the most straightforward solution to the `null` problem, for people coming from a language like Java. In that analogy, `Int` really is a subtype of `Int?`, so every integer is an instance of `Int?`. `3` is an instance of both `Int` and `Int?`, and it means both "this is an integer" and also "this is an integer which is optional but exists".

That approach works fine in languages with subtyping. If your language is built up from a typical OOP hierarchy, it's easy to say "well, `T` is clearly a subtype of `T?`" and move on. But Elm isn't built that way. There's no subtyping relationships in Elm (there's unification, which is a different thing). Elm is based on Haskell, which is built up from the [Hindley-Milner model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system). In this model, every value has a unique type.

Whereas in Kotlin, `3` is an instance of `Int`, and also `Int?`, and also `Number`, and also `Number?`, and so on all the way up to `Any?` (the top type in Kotlin), there is no equivalent in Elm. There is no "top type" that everything inherits from, and there is no subtyping. So it's not meaningful to say that `3` is an instance of multiple types. In Elm, `3` is an instance of `Int`. End of story. That's it. If a function takes an argument of type `Int`, it *must* be an integer. And since `3` can't be an instance of some other type, we need another way to represent "an integer that may or may not be there".

```
type Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Enter optional typing. `3` can't be an optional integer, since it's an `Int` and nothing else. But `Just 3`, on the other hand... `Just 3` is an entirely different value and *its* type is `Maybe Int`. A `Just 3` is *only* valid in situations where an optional integer is expected, since it's not an `Int`. `Maybe a` is what's called an optional type; it's a completely separate type which represents the type `a`, but optional. It serves the same purpose and `T?` in a language like Kotlin, but it's built up from different foundations.

Getting into which one is better would derail this post, and I don't think that's important here. I have my opinions, but others have theirs as well. Optional typing and nullable typing are two different approaches to dealing with values that may or may not exist. Elm (and Haskell-like languages) use one, and other languages might use the other. A well-rounded programmer should become comfortable with both.

Comment: Great answer! "*Getting into which one is better …*" - I'm curious now, though. Is there anything that's much (!) easier to do with one than with the other? Is there any idiom (or edge case) where they are semantically different?

Comment: Wow, it makes sense! It really seems more logic now to separate the two kinds. Thank you so much for the awesome answer.

Comment: @Bergi The main factor for me is that optional types compose better. Namely, `Maybe (Maybe a)` is a distinct type from `Maybe a` (`Nothing` and `Just Nothing` are distinguishable), whereas `(T?)?` is equivalent to `T?` and only has one `null`. This can bite you when doing things with generics where the generic might or might not already be nullable. Not a huge problem, but it's why I personally prefer `Maybe` to nullable types. On the other hand, being able to implicitly upcast `Int` to `Int?` is nice for ergonomics and code readability, so both sides have their advocates.

Answer (score 3):

> Why an integer is not considered a `Just Int` if I don't add the `Just` word before?

Simply because without the constructor (`Just`), it's only an integer and not something else. There's no automatic type conversion, you have to be explicit about what you want. Would you also consider allow writing `100` if you meant the single-element list `[100]`? Soon, you would have no idea what it meant if someone wrote `100`.

This is not specific to `Maybe` and its `Just` variant, this is the rule for all data types. There is no exception for Maybes, even if the language is confusing - an `Int` is just an `Int`, but not a `Just Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in Elm is a tag but in this context you can think of it like  a function that takes a value  of type `Int`, and return something of the type `Maybe Int`.

Answer (score 0):

```hs
type Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
---
Just 123 -- is a `Maybe Int`
```

Means `Maybe` is a type with an associated generic type `a`. Similar to C++'s `T`

```cpp
template <class T>
class Maybe

using MaybeInt = Maybe<Int>
```

All `Nothing` and `Just a` are are functions (aka constructors) to make a `Maybe`. In Python it might look like:

```py
def Nothing() -> Maybe:
    return Maybe() # except in elm, it knows the returned Maybe came from a
                   # Nothing, so there's some machinery missing here

def Just(some_val) -> Maybe:
    return Maybe(some_val)
```

So if a function returns a Maybe, the returned value has to be passed through one of the two `Nothing` or `Just` constructors.